# Parametric Solution to system of two quadratic equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametrization

Is there a way I can find a parametric (rational) solution to the following system:

$$\begin{cases}& x^2-y^2 = 2\\ &8x^2-z^2 = 7 \end{cases}.$$

I know a solution $(x,y) = (\frac{p^2+2q^2}{2pq}, \frac{p^2-2q^2}{2pq})$ satisfies the first equation alone.

Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I already edited the question.

Comment: Do you know a rational solution? Otherwise there might be just no rational parametrization.

Comment: I was able to show that the equation can be written as a quartic. Which may be an elliptic curve. So explicit parametrization might not be possible.

Comment: We can extend the parametrization to $z$ if and only if $2p^4+p^2q^2+8q^4$ is a perfect square, namely equal to $z^2(pq)^2$. However, I haven't found an integer solution to $r^2=2p^4+p^2q^2+8q^4$. What is your quartic equation?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes. I haven't found one either.

Comment: Do we have a reason to expect there to be any rational solutions at all?